# Create class and make it callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have these classes:

```
class BaseElement:
   def __init__(self, locator):
       self.locator = locator
    

class ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement(BaseElement):
   def __init__(self, locator, element_to_appear_path):
        super(ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement, self).__init__(locator)
        self.element_to_appear_path = element_to_appear_path

   def __get__(self, obj, owner):
       driver = obj.driver
       element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(self.locator))
       element.click()
       WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located(self.element_to_appear_path))
```

And I'm creating an element using this:

```
class WorkerTimePage:
    time_and_expense_menu = ButtonElement(By.ID, "time_expense")
    timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago = ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement(
    (By.ID, "timesheet_id"),
    (By.XPATH, '//th[@class="workday"]'))
```

What I basically want to do is on my test be able to call just `timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago` and do the actions from my class(in this case just do a click on an element and then wait for a new one), I have my test like this:

```
from cloud_testing.login.page_objects import LoginPage
from cloud_testing.test_base import TestBase
from cloud_testing.worker.page_objects import WorkerTimePage

class TestEditTimesheet(TestBase):

     login_page = None
     worker_time_page = None

     def setup_method(self):
         super(TestEditTimesheet, self).setup_method()
         self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
         self.worker_time_page = WorkerTimePage(self.driver)

     def test_worker_adds_punch_to_timesheet(self):
         self.login_page.login('bescoto@fgeneric.com', 'bescoto')
         self.worker_time_page.time_and_expense_menu.click()
         self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()
```

It does the action of clicking and wait the new element correctly but at the end it triggers this error:

> self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Not sure what I need to change to do what I'm looking for, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share `WorkerTimePage` source code?

Comment: Sorry my bad, basically  'WorkerTimePage' only contains 2 elements , 'time_and_expense_menu and the other one  I already mentioned 'timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago' , time and expense is only a button but the problem is the other one

Comment: It will be much easier, if you edit your post and add source code. Beacuse `self.worker_time_page.time_and_expense_menu.click()` worked fine and program stops on the second method `self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()` and there will be issue. And thats why i wanna see the source code of `WorkerTimePage`.

Answer (score 1):

In first `worker_time_page` you call:

`self.worker_time_page.time_and_expense_menu.click()`

in second you missed method `click()`

`self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()  # .click() is missing`

Becasuse `ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement` has no implementation of `__call__` method, python is returning error.

So i assume you wanna call `.click()`

```py
class ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement(BaseElement):
   def __init__(self, locator, element_to_appear_path):
        super(ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement, self).__init__(locator)
        self.element_to_appear_path = element_to_appear_path

   def click(self):
       driver = obj.driver
       element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(self.locator))
       element.click()
       WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located(self.element_to_appear_path))

class TestEditTimesheet(TestBase):

     login_page = None
     worker_time_page = None

     def setup_method(self):
         super(TestEditTimesheet, self).setup_method()
         self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
         self.worker_time_page = WorkerTimePage(self.driver)

     def test_worker_adds_punch_to_timesheet(self):
         self.login_page.login('bescoto@fgeneric.com', 'bescoto')
         self.worker_time_page.time_and_expense_menu.click()
         self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago.click()  # this was changed
```

Comment: This is not right , I don't wanna call `.click()` for  `ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement`,  I do for `time_and_expense_menu` because `ButtonElement` is different, for `ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement` I'm looking just to call timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago and be able to do a click and then wait a new element( exactly what I have inside the class), not sure if instead of `__get__` I need to use something else

Comment: So then implement `click()` method to `ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement`, it will do the trick, and your code stay consistent.